# Sort table of items based on most/recently viewed item by the user?

Tags: database, algorithm, sorting, timestamp

In a database, what's the best way to sort a table of items based on most viewed/ recently viewed items by the user?

My idea is like to create a  timestamp column and update it each time the user view's an item. Later on sort the table by  timestamp desc.

Is there any other better and efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: That's the way I would do it. I think that could cause a lot of overhead if the database is accessed frequently

Comment: Yes, I know this would be a costly operation that's why I'm looking for a better alternative solution